# Local storage for all activities

Tags: javascript, html

I have created code to capture the button click,but i want to save them locally using local storage.I am unable to store locally y trying localStorage code.Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <table class="calc" cellpadding=2> 
 <tr>
        <td><input type="button" class="calc" id="screen1" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="calc" id="screen2" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="calc" id="screen3" value="0"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="calc" cellpadding=2>
    <tr> 
        <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(1)" value="Call2Functions">1</td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(2)" value="Call2Functions">2</td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(3)" value="Call2Functions">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" id="Check1" name="radio" onclick="check(1)">button1</td>
      <td><input type="radio" id="Check2" name="radio" onclick="check(2)">button2</td>
      <td><input type="radio" id="Check3" name="radio" onclick="check(3)">button3</td>
    </tr>
   </table>


        <script> 
        function check(value){
          if(document.getElementById("Check"+value).checked)
          {
            buttonValue = value;
          }
        }
            function pushButton(addValue) {
    if (buttonValue == 'C') {
        document.getElementById('screen').value = '0';
    }
    else {//this is where most changes occured
        var x= document.getElementById('screen'+buttonValue).value 
        x =parseInt(x)+ parseInt(addValue);
        document.getElementById('screen'+buttonValue).value=x;
        localStorage.setItem('answer', x);
    }
}

    function calculate(equation) {
        var answer = eval(equation);
        document.getElementById('screen'+buttonValue).value = answer;
    }
                         </script>
                         </body>
                         </html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you've run into any errors, what are they? The more information you provide, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no problem with localStorage , I tried to reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle.  Please see the link below.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/1axfLgw2/`
```

Comment: Hi @KishoreSahas i do not want separate button to show stored value.what ever i am entering it gets stored if i refreshed or closed the app the data should not go away

Comment: @SANTHIYA, I think i understood ur issue, I have done some changes in the logic please see (http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/1axfLgw2/)

Comment: And also the problem was in the logic not in localStorage. Please compare the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Is it possible to select two radio button and add value in the both?

Comment: @ KishoreSahas, Thank you. Is it possible to select two radio buttons and add value in both? and add undo button if suppose we add any numbers wrongly to go back?

Comment: you need use check box in that case

Comment: Hi @KihoreSahas ,your answer was very helpful but now i want to remove localStorage how i havr to do that? I tried but unable to do it

Comment: localStorage.clear() will clear all the items in local storage.

Comment: can you explain how i have to clear localStorage & display value also

Comment: i have updated  (http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/1axfLgw2/5). u just have to set the values to zero ..

Comment: @ KishoreSahas, is it possible to add one more function? Now its adding the value in button,but i want to create one more button where it should count the click counting.both have to function by single click after clicked one radio button and is it possible to click two radio button and add value in both? kindly help me with your code///

Comment: @SANTHIYA , i didn't understand your issue, it will be nice if you could share the code you have tried out ..